NUnit Test Adapter is running up Explicit test by default
I have a unit test project running in .net6.0 with a simple explicit test.
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void Hello()
    {
        Assert.That(1 == 1, Is.True);
    }
}

I am running this test from Visual 2022 test explorer by clicking the run all button. for this project in particular it is picking up the explicit test and trying to execute it.

The [Explicit] attribute is respected in the other project as can be seen on the screenshot above.
I am guessing there is a setting somewhere which is directing the discovery mode for this project but i could not find it.
Below is the current version of the assemblies from the csproj file.
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.12.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="5.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="4.2.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.6.0" />
</ItemGroup>

I have also gone through things like, cleaning the solution, exiting visual studio and restarting the machine with no luck.
